# why is my recursion not returning the desired output?

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing a recursion function that simply returns x^n:

```
def myPow(x,n) -> float:
    def recurs_n(x,n):
        if n==1:
            return x

        if n>1:
            result = myPow(x,n-1)

        return result

    return recurs_n(x,n)


print(myPow(2,5))
```

The output that I am getting for the above is 2, which isn't correct obviously. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Don't you mean `result = x * recurs_n(x,n-1)`?

Comment: ahh yes, that's right

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner function calls the outer function, that should not be allowed. Furthermore, there is no logic applied anywhere for the multiplication when going to the `n-1` step. So when `n>1` you need to return `x*myPow(x,n-1)`

I should also mention, that in your case there is no real need to have an inner and outer function, one function should be enough. Like so;

```py
def myPow(x,n) -> float:
    if n == 1:
        return x
    if n > 1:
        return x*myPow(x,n-1)


print(myPow(2,5))
```

Comment: Thanks oskros, it makes sense. One question, in what instance would it be necessary to have both the inner and outer loop as I have in my code?

Comment: @dhsdnfdsfn that would be relevant in the case where you wish to do some kind of recursive operation, and then afterwards apply some other operation. So for your example, in case you first wanted to recursively calculate a power, and then afterwards translate the result into a string saying `The result of myPow(2, 5) is 32`

Comment: I see, that makes sense too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs until power n=5 reaches 1, where it activates the first if condition where x is returned (here x=2) without continuing onwards.

An alternative is presented below:

```
def power(N, P):

    # if power is 0 then return 1
    if P == 0:
        return 1
  
    # if power is 1 then number is
    # returned
    elif P == 1:
        return N
  
    else:
        return (N*power(N, P-1))
```

Comment: It seems that the indentation in your copied code is wrong

Comment: @oskros It's ok, I am new here. I try to figure out how this site works with trial and error. I fix the indentation.